# solr4 - Error Nodes in Index

Tags: solr, alfresco, solr4

I'm running Alfresco 5.0.c and Solr4.

Documents with custom properties are not searchable. Recently I've migrated from Solr 1.4 to Solr4. Probably this migration caused the problem. But I cannot find any trace of what could be wrong. I've checked solr.log, alfresco.log, nothing there. The only thing I could find is in Solr admin page for Alfresco core I have this message:

```
 Error Nodes in Index: 10
```

10 is exact number of document I've uploaded. Where I can find some info about what exactly is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't try before, you can follow the [Troubleshooting SolR4 index](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/solr-index-fix.html) which may help you to overcome your issues.
Moreover you can always try to perform a full SolR 4 indexes rebuild as stated in [SolR 4 indexes rebuild](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/solr-reindex.html) and monitor the application server logs about SolR.
Take also a close look about how to [configure search properties](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/search-fts-config.html) and remember that

> The data dictionary settings for properties determine how individual properties are indexed